# What is the private attribute of Kubuntu activity?

Tags: kubuntu

When creating a new Kubuntu activity, there is a checkbox labelled "Private - do not keep history of this activity"

What is the history mentioned here? The Konsole history or Kate recently opened document are the same on each activity, including the ones with the private attribute. So of which history are we talking about here?

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Version of KDE plasma : 5.12.9
Version of KDE framework : 5.44.0
Qt version : 5.9.4
Kernel version : 4.15.0-74-generic
64-bit

```
phil@GlaDOS:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: Please always provide the version number of your OS when asking questions because the answer may depend on that. For Kubuntu, the output of `plasmashell --version` and `kf5-config --version` would be useful as well. An option, if you're on Kubuntu 19.04 or 19.10, is to open KInfocenter, use "copy to clipboard"  and paste the contents here. Either way, click the **[edit]** link below your question to add additional content.